# Combining Docbook and Doxygen documentation types.

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen, docbook

I'm working on new documentation for our software library and I'm wondering how I can combine a general documentation which I think should be written in DocBook together with a Doxygen based API reference.

The Doxygen part already exists so I prefer to keep it, but using DocBook is just an idea and I'm open to any ideas. Writing the whole documentation in Doxygen is possible but it does not seem to me to be the best approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about Docbook, but Doxygen can output to Docbook if there is a way to combine that output with other Docbook files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to reconsider going the all-Doxygen way. Even though writing elaborate documentation using Doxygen may seem cumbersome at first, keeping two Documentations consistent will be more work in the long run. Apart from the added workload you have by combining the output products of both.

Doxygen makes it possible to include Markdown files as pages into your documentation (see [this section](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_page_header) of the manual that) and to externalize elaborate documentation in order to not blow up your source files too much (see [this other section](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands) of the manual).

I should also add that I have had no previous first-hand experience with Docbook, so that might bias me a bit towards Doxygen.

Comment: This one was practically selected. This is not flexible enough and i would prefer over solution, but it's good enough.